# Where is the cupsctl terminal executable on MacOSX?

Tags: macos, shell, unix, find, cups

I've looked everywhere, and can't seem to find cupsctl anywhere. I assume it's a lot like echo or sh, it's just an executable with a PATH variable sat somewhere on the system. In order for me to call an NSTask from an Obj-C app I'm working on, I need to know where it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [UNIX find command](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html) to search your entire disk starting at the root

e.g. `find / -name 'cupsctl'`

Shouldn't actually take all that long assuming an average sized SSD. A couple of seconds on my Mac

```
$ sudo find / -name 'cupsctl' 2> /dev/null 
/usr/sbin/cupsctl
```

or, as it's OS X, if you have spotlight indexes you could use mdfind

`mdfind -name 'cupsctl'`

which returns instantly with a few results, most of which are Safari history for this page :-)